# user not recognized from the recovery mode

Tags: users

I wanted to add my user account to another group so I booted into recovery mode and chosen the `Drop to root shell` option but when i type in the shell 
`usermod -a -G aGroup myUsername` it tells me that the user does not exist.

I can login by myUsername and the `whoami` command give my my valid username.

I do not know where is the problem.

for information :

- the computer(s) is on my school , and all the student of the shcool have an account ,
- we can log in from all the pc(s) in the school network.

I want to know too how they can setup this mechanism (about 1000 user can log in from any computer by their username)? Did they create the accounts for each computer?

Comment: School computers, eh? Probably using LDAP, in which case you won't be able to modify the user's group anyway. Contact your school's IT dept.

Comment: yees , riiight , LDAP , i know that they use LDAP , can you explain how they did it , and why i cant modify the user's group if it is the case !!!!

Comment: you can't modify because any sane LDAP setup requires administrator access to the LDAP service to modify group membership (which is not the same as administrative access to an individual PC). As to how, there are articles on setting up Ubuntu as LDAP servers and clients which you can look up.

Comment: a last thing , 
can you give me a usefull article about 'setting up Ubuntu as LDAP servers and clients' , 
i can search for it on google but since am a beginner in this , i need to have a valid source ! 
thank you again

Comment: The Ubuntu LTS server guide covers it: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openldap-server.html

Comment: thank you ^^,
how can i mention your response as a valid one ??

Comment: I'll convert it to an answer. Hold on a moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a school setup, they are probably using LDAP for authentication, in which case you won't be able to modify group membership. You'll have to contact your school's IT department or system administrator.

You can't modify them because because any sane LDAP setup requires administrator access to the LDAP service to modify group membership (which is not the same as administrative access to an individual PC). Tools like `adduser` and `usermod` work on local users, which are set up in `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`.

To see how to configure an Ubuntu system as an LDAP server or client, see the Ubuntu LTS server guide article on [OpenLDAP](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openldap-server.html).

Comment: As an added bonus: The school IT department should be contacted to enact this change